# How to use TimerTask on flutter?

Tags: flutter, timertask

I want to create a function that runs every x seconds ..

in java there is the

```
TimerTask
```

but in flutter what is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import 'dart:async'; // import this
```

And use `Timer` class `periodic` named constructor.

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
  // this block runs every second
  // and when you want to stop it, simply call `timer.cancel();` here
});
```